# SharePoint web part automatic refresh javascript event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, accordion, jslink

**Background**: I'm modifying a SharePoint list web part using JSLink. I'm also adding jQuery and jQuery-UI to make the list items display as the jQuery Accordion. It works well, except that I also need to implement the ajax automatic refresh on the web part to refresh the content every 60 seconds.

**Problem**: When the web part refreshes, the jquery code reverts - the items no longer show in accordion mode. I can open the browser console and type the jquery code manually, e.g., `$(".selector").accordion();` and it works fine.  This makes me think that I need to find a way to call the jquery code *after* each web part automatic refresh completes.

**Question**: So, is there a javascript event or way to find out when an automatic refresh triggers on my webpart so that I can call again my jquery accordion after? Is there something else I could be missing?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to use this code:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(MyFunction); 

function MyFunction() { 
    //do something here; 
}
```

Credit to @Thriggle

References:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028.aspx 
https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/247263/ajax-postback-after-endrequest

Comment: Feel free to mark this as the answer (now that you've got 15+ reputation) so people know your question is resolved. (And yes, [it's kosher to answer your own questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)!)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can insert your own code or function calls into the callback chain by overriding the `_onFormSubmit` method of the current instance of the `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager` object.

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._onFormSubmit = function(i){

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.prototype._onFormSubmit.call(this,i);

    alert("Refreshing the data..."); // -- your code or function call here

};
```

When I ran the above code in the F12 console on a page with a list view that had a 25-second refresh, I started seeing the "Refreshing the data..." pop-up every 25-seconds, but I haven't tested it with anything more complicated than that.

Comment: Actually, your response let me to my answer. The code you gave me runs _right before_ the auto-refresh happens. I need it _right after_. So I looked on the web and found a very similar code: 

`Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(MyFunction);

MyFunction() {
     //do something here;
}`

I want to give you credit for the answer. @Thriggle

Comment: I'm glad I helped a little! Good find with the  [Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028.aspx) MSDN class reference.